# Передача параметров

Tags: java

```
package com.example.test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class LoadImage {

    /**
     * подгружаем картику
     */

    public static BufferedImage loadImage() throws IOException {
        return ImageIO
            .read(new File("C:\\Users\\GJ\\IdeaProjects\\Test\\src\\com\\example\\test\\1.bmp"));
    }


    /**
     * Переводим в матрицу
     */
    public static int[][] convertToMatrix(BufferedImage image) {

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        /**System.out.println(w);
         System.out.println(h);*/

        int[][] matrix = new int[w][h];
        /**int [][] red = new int [w][h];
         int [][] green = new int [w][h];
         int [][] blue = new int [w][h];*/

        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));

                /** red[i][j] = color.getRed();
                 green[i][j] = color.getGreen();
                 blue[i][j] = color.getBlue();
                 matrix[i][j] = (red[i][j] + blue[i][j] + green[i][j])/3;*/

                matrix[i][j] = (color.getBlue() + color.getGreen() + color.getRed()) / 3;

                /** System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);*/
            }
        }

        return matrix;


    }

}
```

Если я думаю не правильно выправите пожалуйста)
Вот здесь мы получаем матрицу и возвращаем ее значение в метод convertToMatrix (это и будет переменной???) и мне нужно в другом класе вызвать эту матрицу для продолжения работы с ней)

```
package com.example.test;


public class Etalon {

    public static int[] etalonMatrix(convertToMatrix) {

    }
}
```

Но я не могу понять как правильно передавать парамтры.
 Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: объявление будет видимо `public static int[] etalonMatrix(int[][] convertToMatrix)`.......... а вызов его будет типа такого `Etalon.etalonMatrix(LoadImage.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.loadImage()))` ........то есть мы в etalonMatrix передаем аргумент двумерный массив, который возвращается из статического метода, который принимает аргумент картинку, возвращамый другим статическим методом

Comment: return matrix; - а эта строка мне точно массив возвращает?? как это проверить? 
ведь после выхода из цикла мы теряем переменную?

Comment: @ДашаНовикова 1- мы видим тип возвращаемого значения int[][], а значит возвращает двумерный массив типа int. 2- результат выполнения метода присвоить к переменной, тогда не потеряешь результат

Answer (score 0):

> return matrix; - а эта строка мне точно массив возвращает?? как это
>   проверить? ведь после выхода из цикла мы теряем переменную?

Да это массив. Так как выше ты объявила его двумерным массивом. Он может быть пустым, не верно забитым, но это массив. Убедиться в этом можно выведя его на экран.
И выйдя из цикла мы не теряем значение, так как переменная объявлена не внутри цикла, а внутри метода и существует до окончания метода.

---

Вы не правы. В приведенном коде не происходит передачи матрицы. А лишь описаны методы для конвертирования и загрузки изображения.

А для получения в другом классе:

```
LoadImage.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.load‌​Image());
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя класс LoadImage в том же пакете, и матрица в методе собирается правильно:

```
public class Etalon {
   int [][] newMatrix = new int[][]
 newMatrix= LoadImage.convertToMatrix(image);
}
```